# Big Query insert row from python - what is insert_row() method format?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I have a python program that stores values in a database.  I'd like to store them in Big Query instead of locally. From the [Big Query docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python) I've looked at this example:

```
rows_to_insert = [(u"Phred Phlyntstone", 32), (u"Wylma Phlyntstone", 29)]
```

Where can I find a detailed explanation of how this works?  What should go where and how it should be formatted. I have created a table with a schema (name, date, age).  When I create my own `rows_to_insert` do i treat each field ("Phred", 2345-02-19, 44) as the column defined by the schema?

If so, can I use a variable here?  If I can, can someone give a quick example of what that looks like? (x, y, z) or ({x}, {y}, {z}) or ((x), (y), (z)).

In the example above each row entry starts with a 'u'.  Why?

the general syntax I have seen is:

```
INSERT INTO ‘table_name’
(column1, column2, column3, - - - )
VALUES (value1, value2, value3 - - -)
```

Am I able to use this syntax?

Thanks for reading my post.  If I've made a mistake in how I've phrased my question of if you have a suggestion on how to present it more clearly please let me know and I'll adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the reference for this function [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows)
About how it should be formatted, the documentation says the following:

> - **rows (Union[Sequence[Tuple], Sequence[dict]])** – Row data to be
>   inserted. If a list of tuples is given, each tuple should contain data
>   for each schema field on the current table and in the same order as
>   the schema fields. If a list of dictionaries is given, the keys must
>   include all required fields in the schema. Keys which do not
>   correspond to a field in the schema are ignored.

It means that you must use as arguments a list of tuples with ordered values corresponding to the fields in your table. The other possibility is to send a list of dictionaries specifying the fields as keys and the data to be inserted as values in each field.
If you're using variables, you should just put your variable name instead of a literal value in your tuple or in your dictionary's value field.
For example, if you have two variables x and y, you could do: `(x,y)` or `{'key1':x, 'key2': y}` where key1 and key2 are the name of the fields in your table.

About the `u`being used before a string: it's a `Python` notation for unicode strings. You should use that when you work with unicode encoding.

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not sure why I couldn't find that link but it was exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to store all values in a list and pass the list to insert_rows().

Regarding unicode encoding, does the 'u' need to precede every string in a list?  Which would be correct:
x = [u"stuff", u"more stuff", u"less stuff"]
or
x = [u"stuff", "more stuff", "less stuff"]

Comment: It depends on which version Python you are using. If you're using Python 3, you can only do ["stuff", "more stuff", "less stuff"]. If you're using Python 2, you probably should do  [u"stuff", u"more stuff", u"less stuff"].
I think this article can clarify it for you https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2017/sep/05/how-python-does-unicode/